# Can we create certificate sign request (CSR) using HSM(Safenet) in Objective C or Swift?

Tags: swift, pkcs#10, safenet

I am trying to create csr in swift, given that i am creating key-pair in safenet dongle using their sdk.

I am trying to do the csr generation in native code.In my sdk source code, some of the mechanisms are missing(for example PKCS_ENCODE_10, CKO_CERTIFICATE_REQUEST etc.

Is there any wrapper in (.mm format) which generate csr for from private key, public key and data?